# Clojure Empty Sequence Behaviour

Tags: clojure

I'm relatively new to Clojure and have been working through 4Clojure. I'm working on problem 31, Pack a Sequence, http://www.4clojure.com/problem/31#prob-title. The goal is to pack consecutive duplicates into sub-lists. I know this can be achieved using `(partition-by ...)` but I wanted to attempt writing it out in full using `(loop ... (recur ...))`. My attempt is as follows:

```
(defn my-subpack
[paramSeq]
;Track the output sequence
;Track the current sub sequence
;Track the next input value to consider
(loop [outSeq  []
     currSub (vector (first paramSeq))
     inSeq   (rest paramSeq)]
    ;If the inSeq is empty then we return outSeq
    (println (empty? inSeq))
    (if (empty? inSeq)
      outSeq)
    ;If the next value from inSeq is in the currSub then we add it to it
    (if (= (first currSub) (first inSeq))
      (recur outSeq (conj currSub (first inSeq)) (rest inSeq))
      (recur (conj outSeq currSub) (vector (first inSeq)) (rest inSeq)))
    ))
```

The program seems to get stuck in an infinite loop so I ran it through my IDE's debugger. It appears that when `inSeq` is empty the `if` statement to return `outSeq` does not get run. It is skipped over as if `(empty? inSeq)` returns `false`. Below I've included a screenshot of the IDE when the infinite loop begins. Notice that `(count inSeq)` returns 0 in the expression evaluator but the debugger shows it as having a count of 1. Here is the IDE when Infinite Loop begins. Count shows 0 in expression evaluator but it also shows 1 in debugger.

[image]

It feels likely to me I've made some huge oversight but I just amn't experienced enough to see it yet!

Comment: Your first `if` there is a no-op.  It does not work like in imperative programming.  It must must be the last operation in a form to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when `inSeq` is empty, the machine just does nothing and proceeds to the next statement (which does `recur` in both cases). What you probably want is to return `outSeq` as the result of the loop expression if `inSeq` is empty:

```
(if (empty? inSeq)
  outSeq
  ;; If the next value from inSeq is in the currSub then we add it to it
  (if (= (first currSub) (first inSeq))
    (recur outSeq (conj currSub (first inSeq)) (rest inSeq))
    (recur (conj outSeq currSub) (vector (first inSeq)) (rest inSeq))))
```